# How to compute cshot descriptors using pcl::SHOTColorEstimation

Tags: visual-c++, point-cloud-library

I'm working on 3D feature descriptors. Now I want to compute cshot descriptors using pcl::SHOTColorEstimation , but there is no more detailed introduction. Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
#include <pcl/features/shot.h>
pcl::SHOTEstimation<pcl::PointXYZRGB,pcl::Normal,pcl::SHOT1344> shot_est;
shot_est.setInputCloud(keypoints);
shot_est.setInputNormals(normal_cloud);
shot_est.setSearchSurface(search_cloud);
shot_est.setSearchMethod(pcl::search::KdTree<PointT>::Ptr (new pcl::search::KdTree<PointT>));
shot_est.setRadiusSearch(search_radius);
shot_est.compute(*descriptor);
```

where the Input Cloud could consist of pre-computed Keypoints, then you would need the original cloud to calculate the descriptors on (setSearchSurface), or you compute the descriptors on every point of the input cloud, then just disregard 'setSearchSurface'. The search radius depends on how dense your cloud is, you have to find out on your own.

Greetz

Comment: I want to ask you a similar problems. Is there a way to compute spin descriptors only for the pre-computed Keypoints? For what I have searched seem like to compute spin descriptors for all points in the point cloud.

Comment: Yes you have to compute them on the input cloud as the input normals have to match the input cloud